# How to create a table which has bunch of other tables w/o merging?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datatable, backend

My object is to create a new table that has multiple other tables.

So a diagram would be like this:

[image]

And this is a query of the table. Each tables have the same column names; `id`, `name` and `address`:

```
CREATE TABLE internal (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(10),
    address VARCHAR(6)
); -- the other tables have same design.

insert into internal(name, address) values ("Jack", "AZ");
insert into internal(name, address) values ("Nelson", "NY");
insert into internal(name, address) values ("Tom", "NY");
insert into external(name, address) values ("Peter", "London");
insert into external(name, address) values ("John", "London");
insert into terminal(name, address) values ("Lisa", "CA");
insert into terminal(name, address) values ("Anna", "ND");

CREATE TABLE result AS 
(SELECT internal.*
    FROM internal
    LEFT JOIN external
        ON internal.id = external.id
    LEFT JOIN terminal
        ON external.id = terminal.id
);
```

A problem is mysql merges all of the same name columns automatically whether the other tables have their own data or not.

The result:

```
ID |  NAME  | ADDRESS |
 1 |  Jack  |    AZ   |
 2 | Nelson |    NY   |
 3 |   Tom  |    NY   |
```

I want to create my table like this:

```
ID |  NAME  | ADDRESS | ID |  NAME  | ADDRESS | ID |  NAME  | ADDRESS |
 1 |  Jack  |    AZ   |  1 |  Peter |  London |  1 |  Lisa  |    CA   | 
 2 | Nelson |    NY   |  2 |  John  |  London |  2 |  Anna  |    ND   |
 3 |   Tom  |    NY   |null|  null  |   null  |null|  null  |   null  |
```

Is this possible in mySQL?

Comment: Having same name for rows is Ok. But no point in having same id and different values in NAME column in single row. Very poorly organized database. And nothing productive this could be. Better start again with what you expect to arrive at. We shall help.

Comment: @nnn My expectation is to join some of the tables to 1 individual table so I don't need to call every each one of the tables in the server. Is this still bad idea? (I'm a new guy at database so please excuse if this is poor idea.)

Comment: Yes. You could design in a much better way.

Comment: Looking at your negative reply to the other Answer, ** Better start again with what you expect to arrive at. We shall help**

Answer (score 0):

You need to select from all the tables:

```
SELECT i.*, e.*, t.*
FROM internal i LEFT JOIN
     external e
     ON i.id = e.id LEFT JOIN
     terminal t
     ON e.id = t.id;
```

Tables cannot have columns with duplicate names, so yo might need to rename them:

```
SELECT i.id, i.name, i.address,
       e.id_e, e.name_e, e.address_e,
       t.id_t, t.name_t, t.address_t
```

Comment: Thanks for tip but it gives an error like this: `Duplicate column name id`. I changed all of the single letters to the full table names like: `internal.* external.*, terminal.*` and tried again, but it throws the same error. Did I miss something in your answer?

Comment: @sniffingdoggo . . . Yes you missed something.  Half the answer.  The answer addresses exactly that issue.